# Изменение содержания QLineEdit и взятие строки после изменения

Tags: qt

Здравствуйте! Недавно понадобилось разобраться в `Qt GUI`, и встретилась мне одна проблема с `QLineEdit`. В общем, есть у меня объект типа `QLineEdit`, и использую я его в `QWizardPage`. В программе указаны начальный адрес, который можно редактировать. Как после редактирования обращаться к тексту, который написан в объекте `QLineEdit`. Знаний в `Qt` мало, не судите строго.

```
QLabel oldWay = new QLabel("Way to Existed File:"); 
QLineEdit oldWayEdit = new QLineEdit;

QLabel newWay = new QLabel("Way to Created File:"); 
QLineEdit newWayEdit = new QLineEdit;
```

Дальше в этих полях изменяются данные, и мне нужно взять измененные данные. Я не знаю, как. Смотрел на `Qt Project` все функции, но безрезультатно

Comment: Воспользуйтесь [`oldWayEdit->text()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#text-prop).

Comment: Пользовался, но он будет хранить только начальные данные, а какой функцией воспользоваться, чтобы после того, как я произвожу изменения, можно было сохранить новые данные.

Comment: А можно ли так сделать?

вот у меня есть исходный пустой oldWayEdit->text()
далее я его проверяю с помощью ..->isModified()
а после этого пользуюсь oldWayEdit->textChanged(только не понимаю, что сюда вводить нужно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oldWayEdit->text() будет хранить сначала начальные данные, а после редактирования текста новые данные. Какие данные достанутся Вам зависит от того в какой момент Вы их считываете :)
Обычно новые данные считывают из полей ввода при возникновении следующих событий:

- закрытие формы с полями ввода
- переключении на новую страницу (многостраничные формы)
- окончание ввода в конкретное поле

Давайте рассмотрим последний вариант. Для его реализации Вам нужно написать свой обработчик (slot), в котором Вы будете считывать данные из QLineEdit. Этот слот Вы подключите (функция [connect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect)) к сигналу QLineEdit [editingFinished()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) или [returnPressed()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#returnPressed) (а можно и к обоим). Когда пользователь закончит ввод текста, QLineEdit испустит сигнал editingFinished(), а Ваш слот, прицепленный к этому сигналу, прочитает новый текст. Вот и всё.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Написали как раз то, что я и хотел понять. Спасибо за разъяснение!